# DigitalMicrograph beamshift scripting

Tags: dm-script

I am trying to write a script using the EMSetBeamShift function, but since the input was long (int), the smallest shift I can make is 1.

My question is what is the unit of this movement, and how can I make a smaller beam shift?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know who downvoted the questions and why, but it is a perfectly valid coding question for the scripting languages of DigitalMicrograph and appropriately tagged. So it should not have been downvoted. See my answer below, and welcome to StackOverflow! (Please also accept posted answers, if they answer your question to your satisfaction.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `EMSetBeamShift()` is directly mapped onto the according functionality of the microsccope's API, so the received action depends on what microscope you have (and is outside DM-scripting control).

However, if you have a calibrated microscope you should be able to use the command 
`EMSetCalibratedBeamShift()` instead.

See also the examples in the F1 help section to this topic:
[image]